# date & time difference format

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime

I have a Login/Logout system that compute the total hours work of the employees. My problem is the formatting of the date&time difference for minutes.

Example:

if user logged-in **`8:00 AM`** and logged-out **`6:30 PM`**, the total should be **`10.50`** but my SQL output is **`10 hrs and 30 mins`**. I know the formula(it should be `30mins/60 = 50`) but I didn't know where should I put that Dividend(**`/60`**) on my SQL Query.`(see below my SQL Code)`.

**SQL Code:**

```
SELECT *,CAST(Datediff(HOUR, 0, logout_time - login_time) + 
         Cast(Datediff(MINUTE, 0, logout_time - login_time) - 
             (Datediff(HOUR, 0, logout_time - login_time) * 60 ) AS DECIMAL) / 100 AS Decimal(18,2)) AS [TotalHrs_Worked]
FROM table_DTR
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),log_date, 101) BETWEEN '09/01/2014' AND '11/30/2014'
```

Comment: DATEDIFF(minute, logout_time, login_time) / 60

Comment: @adrianm: I also tried that. but it gives me no luck

Comment: `SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, '20141215 08:00:00', '20141215 18:30:00') / 60.0` gives me `10.50000`

Comment: have you tried my sql? using your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply take the minutes between a pair of datetime values and multiply it by `60.0` (with a decimal place so it produces a result with a decimal value), this should work without problem:

Run this example:

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '2014-12-15 08:00:00'
DECLARE @end DATETIME = '2014-12-15 18:30:00'

SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, @start, @end)/60.0 AS HoursWorked
```

This will produce:

```
10.50
```

You shouldn't need to break it down in to minutes and hours like you are doing in your SQL.